# 2D array interpretation

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Was trying a piece of code like this below and found that things were not happening the way it was expected to be to store values in the array indices. Please check the code snippet below and the output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[2][2];
    int i,j,count_ld_x=0,count_rd_x=0;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("Inputing value for the element:a[%d][%d]",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=%d\n",i,j,a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Input and Output:-**

>  ./main
>
> Inputing value for the element:a[0][0]0
>
> Inputing value for the element:a[0][1]1
>
> Inputing value for the element:a[0][2]2
>
> Inputing value for the element:a[1][0]3
>
> Inputing value for the element:a[1][1]4
>
> Inputing value for the element:a[1][2]5
>
> Inputing value for the element:a[2][0]6
>
> Inputing value for the element:a[2][1]7
>
> Inputing value for the element:a[2][2]8
>
> a[0][0]=0
>
> a[0][1]=1
>
> a[0][2]=3
>
> a[1][0]=3
>
> a[1][1]=4
>
> a[1][2]=6
>
> a[2][0]=6
>
> a[2][1]=7
>
> a[2][2]=8

**Confusion:-** Am storing a[0][2] with 2 and the o/p am getting for the same position is 3. Can you please explain what's the issue?

Comment: When an array is declared with size `[2]` the indices are 0 and 1. `2` is out of bounds.

Comment: Change all `<3` to `<2`, or change the array to `a[3][3]`.

Comment: _Everyone_  learning C makes this bug, so I'd suggest reading the chapter about arrays in your beginner level C programming book. The key is that understanding that declaring array size and performing array access are two different things, the latter using 0-indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you actually intended to do this to see what happens, but you created a 2x2 array and then tried to access positions of the type a[2][*] and a[*][2]. Look at the limits in your iterations, for instance "for(i=0;i< **3** ;i++)". Trying to access memory outside the bounds of arrays results in **Undefined Behavior**.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior